# Multiple session in mininet

Tags: linux, networking, sdn, mininet

Can anybody help me to know what does the "implement a two node in mininet with the two competing session" means and also help me with any reference material if possible?

Comment: Would be useful if you provide where you saw that "implement a two node in mininet with the two competing session". I assume whatever tutorial/book you saw meant having two mininet endpoints (terminals).

Comment: Means I only want to know that how to transmit multiple session between two host. Because to transmit n session we need to change tcp port. But how to do that changing of port I don't know. If could help me with this it could be a great help.

Comment: Still do not get it... Can you give a concrete example of what you want to achieve? Running different applications on mininet hosts is pretty straightforward. Say if you run a TCP server on host 1, then you can run a tcp client on host 2 and use host1's IP to connect.

Comment: Basically I wanted to implement two session between two nodes in TC

Comment: Perhaps I am confused by your two sessions, but mininet uses TC to connect its nodes. Having two sessions is as easy as, for example, starting two iperf servers on the first node, and then connecting to each of the servers from the second node. I do not think anyone would be able to help without much context.

Comment: Thanks for your help I got my point. And the next thing I wanted to ask that in iperf -P 2 the two parallel session is generated with fix bandwidth or the bandwidth we mentioned. But if we wanted to set different bandwidth to different session then what it is the command of iperf. Any idea??

Comment: Iperf is just a performance testing tool. Assuming you use the TCP version it would just send traffic to saturate the link and then back-off as defined per the TCP implementation. If you want to have two different link speeds, simply create two different links with the desired speed and start servers on each node.